# dispatch_group_notify doesn't get called

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to convert couple of locations to `[CLPlacemark]` to draw path on a map. However dispatch_group_notify doesn't call my completion block.

**ViewController.swift**

```
var locationManager:LocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = LocationManager(company: companyType, locations: locations)
    locationManager.getPointsfromLocations { points in
        print("Original Locations",locations)
        print("Converted Points",points)
    }
}
```

**LocationManager.swift**

```
protocol Locatable: class {
     static func normalizeLocation(location:String) ->String
 }

class LocationManager {
    var company:BaseCompany.Type
    var locations:[String]

init(company:BaseCompany.Type,locations:[String]) {
    self.company = company
    self.locations = locations
}

func getPointsfromLocations(completion: (points: [CLPlacemark]) -> ()){
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var points = [CLPlacemark]()
    let group = dispatch_group_create()

        for location in self.locations {
            dispatch_group_enter(group)
            var normalizedLocation = ""
            if let companyObject = self.company as? Locatable.Type {
                normalizedLocation = companyObject.normalizeLocation(location)
            } else {
                normalizedLocation = location
            }
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(normalizedLocation)
                { placemarks, error in
                    if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                        points.append(placemark)
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(group)
            }
        }

    dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            completion(points: points)

        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding print statements with counts at your dispatch_group_enter() and your dispatch_group_leave() calls to try to sort out what's happening.

Comment: I did add print and I never see print called inside dispatch_group_notify completion block. I am really puzzled this code should supposedly work. Only way I made it work is by using ```dispatch_group_wait```

Comment: My suggestion was to put print statements at the dispatch_group_enter() and your dispatch_group_leave() calls, to track how many enters vs. how many leaves are performed. If there are more enters than leaves then your notify block won't get called.